# Matlab: How to display Matrix as Image in GUI

Tags: image, matlab, loops, user-interface, matrix

I’m working on my first GUI in Matlab. It’s gonna get kinda big but I’m starting very basic. So far all I’ve got is a button and axes.

I’m looping a matrix that is being updated every time it goes through the loop. I’d like to display this matrix in my GUI.

When I take out “axes(handles.axes1)” my GUI shuts down and a new window opens with exactly the picture I want on my GUI. When I leave it in all I get is Errors:

Reference to a cleared variable handles.

Error in RackWriter>onOff_Callback (line 141)

axes(handles.axes1)

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)

```
    feval(varargin{:});
```

Error in RackWriter (line 42)

```
gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
```

Error in 
@(hObject,eventdata)RackWriter('onOff_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
Error while evaluating DestroyedObject Callback

Anyone knows what I’m doing wrong?

Thanks so much in advance

Here’s how the matrix is created and how i was planning on showing it:

```
        % Reshape data (1D -> 2D array)

data2d = zeros(nrow, ncol);

k = 1;

for i = 1:nrow

   for j = 1:ncol

      data2d(row_index(i), col_index(j)) = data(k);

      k = k + 1;

   end

end


%resize 16x10 image to 160x100 image

data2d_resized = imresize(data2d,10);

%sensetivity

axes(handles.axes1)

imshow(data2d_resized,[0 255]);
```

Comment: Do you call `clear handles` somewhere?

Comment: no. Should I do that in the beginning of my code?

Comment: No but the error message explicitly states that `handles` is a cleared variable which means that it is not accessible when you try to use it.

Comment: How are you running your gui? are you double clicking it in the file explorer? if so, try running it by writing its name in the matlab command window

Comment: im still developing so i have always started it up from the run command in matlab

Comment: Ah ok, sdbonte seem to already solved your problem. Just as a heads up, a common problem with beginners is that if you double click the .fig file, a GUI opens, and seems ready to use, but no callbacks function, and the error looks similar to yours.

Comment: If my answer was the one you were looking for, please consider it accepting it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
    handles.figure = imshow(data2d_resized, [0 255], 'parent', handles.axes1);
```

If you want to update your figure in a later stage, you can then use:

```
    set(handles.figure, 'CData', updated_matrix);
```

Also, make sure to put the next line after each function in you code, it updates the handles:

```
    guidata(hObject,handles);
```

Comment: First of all thanks. It shows the same errors with "handles.figure = imshow(data2d_resized, [0 255], 'parent', handles.axes1);" this time. To be clear the code you see is in a while loop. So the image gets updated everytime. Why does it shut down my GUI, opens a new window and shows the image i wanna see on my GUI?

Comment: I have never encountered this error. I assume the while-loop takes place in one of the Callback-functions? Did you remove the `axes(handles.axes1)`?

Comment: Yes and Yes... If you want i can put my entire code in here

Comment: that might be useful, if it's not too long

Comment: no should be alright. Im reading data from a matrix sensor throug a serial port. I'll take out all the preadded comments from matlab.. one sec

Comment: in line 53 you put `clear all`, which clears everything, including the necessary handles...

Comment: i think theres a problem with my matrix

Comment: When I block out all the image stuff it now gives me "Attempted to access data(55); index out of bounds because numel(data)=54." this

Comment: I don't know what your `data`-matrix looks like, but instead of the double for-loop, you can use `data_2d = reshape(data,nrow,ncol)`. Also, if my answer solves your main problem, please consider to put is as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function varargout = RackWriter(varargin)
    % Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
    gui_Singleton = 1;
    gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                       'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                       'gui_OpeningFcn', @RackWriter_OpeningFcn, ...
                       'gui_OutputFcn',  @RackWriter_OutputFcn, ...
                       'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                       'gui_Callback',   []);
    if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
        gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
    end

    if nargout
        [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
    else
        gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
    end
    % End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


    % --- Executes just before RackWriter is made visible.
    function RackWriter_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)

    % Choose default command line output for RackWriter
    handles.output = hObject;

    % Update handles structure
    guidata(hObject, handles);
    axes(handles.axes2)
    imshow('sensordeckelOben.jpg');

    % UIWAIT makes RackWriter wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
    % uiwait(handles.figure1);


    % --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
    function varargout = RackWriter_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 

    % Get default command line output from handles structure
    varargout{1} = handles.output;


    % --- Executes on button press in onOff.
    function onOff_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to onOff (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

%This is where my stuff begins
    % Preparations
    close all                   %close all figures
    clear all                   %clear all workspace variables
    fclose('all')               %close all Files
    delete(instrfindall)        %Reset Com Port
    delete(timerfindall)        %Delete Timers
    %clear handles

    % setup serial
    serialPort = serial('COM3');
    command = 'A';

    nrow = 16;
    ncol = 10;
    row_index = [9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1];
    col_index = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

    % 10x16 = 160 bytes
    lendata = 160;

    BaudRate = 115200;

    %InputBufferSize is bein displayed (disp(serialPort.BytesAvailable))
    %with only 322 Bytes. The more information it has to process, the more
    %bytes that havve to be stored in the InputBufferSize. But it seams to
    %not go over 400
    InputBufferSize = 500;

    Timeout = 1;

    set(serialPort , 'BaudRate', BaudRate);
    set(serialPort , 'InputBufferSize', InputBufferSize);
    set(serialPort , 'Timeout', Timeout);

    fopen(serialPort);

    while 1

    % Request data
    fprintf(serialPort, command);

    % Get data
    %Data is read as string (CSV)
    data_string = fgetl(serialPort);
    data_string_array = strsplit(data_string, ',');
    data = str2double(data_string_array);

    % Reshape data (1D -> 2D array)
    data2d = zeros(nrow, ncol);
    k = 1;
    for i = 1:nrow
       for j = 1:ncol
          data2d(row_index(i), col_index(j)) = data(k);
          k = k + 1;
       end
    end

    %resize 16x10 image to 160x100 image
    data2d_resized = imresize(data2d,10);
    %sensetivity [0 255]
    %axes(handles.axes1)
    imshow(data2d_resized,[0 50]);

    %clean out the InputBufferSize
    flushinput(serialPort)
    end
    fclose(serialPort);
```

Comment: as I commented on my answer below: try removing the `clear all` command

Comment: I don't really see where the problem is. Maybe put line 29 after line 31, but this shouldn't solve the problem. For sure, don't clear the `handles`. Also, put `guidata(hObject,handles);` at the end of every function. Try avoiding the `close all` command, rather specify certain figures you want to close.

Comment: ok thanks. since I blocked out all my close all lines I get a immage displayed where I want it. But i still get errors and it wont update itself.

Comment: If you have specific questions, I'm happy to help. As far as the updating is concerned: try my answer below: initialise the figure with the first line, update the figure with the second line.